# QT set window background

Tags: c++, qt, palette

I have scoured through the documentation looking for a way to change the main window's background to an image I have located in the project file. I tried to use a palette with no luck. My question is, how and what is the easiest way to change the background of a window?

Thank You for any help,
Zach Smith

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095957/qt-creator-and-main-window-background-image

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using the Qt StyleSheet ?

Example :

```
QMainWindow{
 background-image: url(:/images_section/application_icon);
 }
```