# Qt Creator and main window background image

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt-creator

I would like to add an image as background of my main window.

What is the best way to add this background image?

The remaining part of my main window must be transparent.

I would like to do this by `QtCreator` editor (for this component, therefore, no code)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While editing your main window form find **styleSheet** property, and put something like this:

```
background: url(:/path/to-your-resource.png)
```

Comment: Agreed, so +1, @GgSalent, just adding that the path defined there assumes that the png is defined in your resources qrc file.

Answer (score 15):

You can add a background image to your `MainWindow` by doing the following:

1. create a `QPixmap` and give it the path to your image.
2. create a `QPalette` and set it's `QBrush` with your pixmap and it's `ColorRole` to `QPalette::Background`.
3. set your `MainWindow` palette to the palette you created.

as an example you can add this lines to the constructor of your `MainWindow` class:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QPixmap bkgnd("/home/user/Pictures/background.png");
    bkgnd = bkgnd.scaled(this->size(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio);
    QPalette palette;
    palette.setBrush(QPalette::Background, bkgnd);
    this->setPalette(palette);
}
```

the advantage with this one is that you have the ability of modifying/changing your background image programmatically without having to use or learn any css stylesheet syntaxes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a `<QGraphicsScene>` eg. `scene` in your main window, then you can do `scene->setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QImage(":/path/to/img.extension")));`. You need to first add the image as a QT Resource in your project, you specify this in the path/argument with `:`.

You should supply an image that complies with the scene dimensions that you ought to have previously set, by eg. `scene->setSceneRect(0,0,myWidth,myHeight);`.